# Lua how to access global variable of another file

Tags: lua, love2d

I am trying to make a bird class in Bird.lua and require it in main.lua
However, Bird.lua makes use of a global variables `VIRTUAL_WIDTH` and `VIRTUAL_HEIGHT` defined in main.lua

I have tried requiring main.lua in Bird.lua as well, but I received `loop or previous error loading module` error.

How should I go about doing this?

main.lua

```lua
push = require 'push'
Bird = require 'Bird'

WINDOW_WIDTH = 1280
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 720

VIRTUAL_WIDTH = 512
VIRTUAL_HEIGHT = 288

local background = love.graphics.newImage('background.png')
local backgroundScroll = 0
local BACKGROUND_SPEED = 30
local BACKGROUND_LOOP_POINT = 413

local ground = love.graphics.newImage('ground.png')
local groundScroll = 0
local GROUND_SPEED = 70

...
```

Bird.lua

```lua
require 'main' --error
Bird = {}

function Bird:new(name)
    o = o or {}
    setmetatable(o,self)
    self.__index = self
    o.name = name 

    self.image = love.graphics.newImage('bird.png')

    --returns width of image
    self.width = self.image:getWidth()
    --returns height of image 
    self.height = self.image:getHeight()

    --centering the bird by default
    self.x = VIRTUAL_WIDTH / 2 - (self.width / 2)
    self.y = VIRTUAL_HEIGHT / 2 - (self.height / 2)

    return o
end
```

Comment: You just need to move the definitions of the globals to before your require statements, IF they are going to be needed before they are defined. Also as a matter of no using globals when you dont need them i would suggest wrapping those value into their own modual and requiring that module were ever you need it, this will let you protect them from being changed on any section of the codes whims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completion, I'm providing an answer based on Nifim's comment.

You should move the global variables in a separate file, e.g. `constants.lua`:

```lua
WINDOW_WIDTH = 1280
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 720

VIRTUAL_WIDTH = 512
VIRTUAL_HEIGHT = 288
```

Then, remove the `require 'main'` from `Bird.lua` and `require 'constants'` in your `main.lua`. Note that this will probably make the variables from `constants.lua` globally available which *can* be troubling (see also Nifim's comment).